# Angular - app start Event

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to handle app start event ?

I want to automatic login user after **app start** or app **refresh**.

Where to put my code?

Comment: it should go inside module.run()

Comment: but can I use Http and services inside run() ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any code you want to run on app start (or app refresh) should go inside `module.run()`. You can inject and use dependencies such as `http` or other services just as you can in controllers, etc. For example:

```
var app = ng.module('app', [/* top-level dependencies, modules */]);

app.run(['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

   // any code you want to run on app start/refresh, using any dependencies you've injected

}]);
```